# By looping getting the key of a object and getting the value of a object?

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am looping in an array and by looping I am getting the key and with that key I want to get the value of the object from an array.

```
<ion-list-header *ngFor="let child of item.value[item.key]; let j = index" no-padding>  
            <h2>
             {{ child['layoutName'] }}
            </h2>

             <h1>{{ result[ child['layoutName']] }}</h1>

      </ion-list-header>
```

the result object is:

```
this.result = [{"light1" : true},{"light2" : true},{"light3" : true}]
```

`child['layoutName']` is having key ex. `light1`, `light2`

Comment: what is the data in item..??

Comment: For example child['layoutName'] is having light1 I want to print 'true'

Comment: That is fine but as you are iterating over item.value[item.key].. so my question is what is in item..??

Answer (score 0):

As is, you could create a filter pipe that would return the correct element for your array given a key. Filter pipes are generally [discouraged in angular](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#no-filter-pipe) due to performance reasons, but if your array is small is should not matter.

There is also another option: you could transform your original array into an object, so that you can use it directly.

```
this.result = { "light1" : true,"light2" : true,"light3" : true}
```

Then this would work

```
  <h1>{{ result[ child['layoutName']] }}</h1>
```

Comment: @nitish Which method? Converting it to an object? Do you have any error?

Answer (score 0):

use `Object.keys` for get object `key`

**[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/by-looping-getting-the-key-of-a-object-and-getting-the-value-of?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)**

**.ts file**

```
Object = Object;
result = [{"light1" : true},{"light2" : true},{"light3" : true}];
```

**.html file**

```
<ion-list-header *ngFor="let child of result; let j = index" no-padding>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let keys of Object.keys(child)">
        <p>Keys - {{keys}}</p>
        <p>value - {{child[keys]}}</p>
    </ng-container>
</ion-list-header>
```